# Existe uma maneira de aplicar um estilo CSS nas opções datalist HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu gostaria de modificar o design de exibicao do datalist, mas o navegador nao deixa, sempre mantem uma padrao. É possível aplicar nele algumas propriedades CSS?

o que tentei no css:

```css
#search-suggestions {
position: absolute;
top: 45px;
width: 100%;
max-height: 200px;
overflow-y: scroll;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 5px;
z-index: 1;
}


#search-suggestions option {
padding: 8px;
font-size: 16px;
color: #000;
cursor: pointer;
}


#search-suggestions option:checked {
background-color: #f00;
color: #fff;
}

#search-suggestions option::before {
content: attr(data-url);
float: right;
font-size: 14px;
color: #888;
}

#search-suggestions option:hover::before {
color: #000;
}

#search-suggestions option:checked::before {
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="get">
                <div class="buscar">
                    <div class="search-bar">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar..." id="search-input" list="search-suggestions">
                        <datalist id="search-suggestions" class="browserdata">
                            <option value="Camiseta" data-url="camisetas.html">
                          </datalist>
                        <button type="submit" id="search-button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: datalist é uma estrutura nativa do HTML que herda a aparência do sistema  ou do navegador mas  pode estilizar os elementos ligado a ele (irmão, pais)

Comment: É complicado estilizar alguns elementos de entrada já que os estilos são muito limitados, no qual varia de navegador e sistema operacional, porém caso queira realmente estilizá-los oferecendo o mesmo estilo em todos navegadores/sistemas operacionais, você pode utilizar alguns frameworks e libraries que possua `<datalist>` como parte personalizável de suas documentação ou ir para o trabalho pesado criando um estilo próprio que possua os mesmos recursos que o elemento nativo HTML teria como funcionalidade, acessibilidade e etc.